Laravel is not installing on window 10
please i need help in installing laravel on my laptop..its displaying
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./dammy"
Installing laravel/laravel (v11.5.0)
    Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\Program Files\php-8.3.15-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\php.ini
    Now trying to download from source

In GitDownloader.php line 82:

  git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package> [<directory> [<version>]]]



Are you running a WAMP server?

The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing... git was not found...so did you try installing any of those, and then running it again?? What exactly is your question to us?
